# How to display category name in product page?

Tags: magento2, product, category

I'm using Magento 2, I want to display the category name of the product on the product page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>
<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
   //echo $category->getId();
   echo $category->getname();
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div><span><?php echo $category->getId();?></span></div>
<div class="product-add-form">
    <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_top'); ?>
        <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content'); ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom'); ?>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
    ], function($){
        var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this at

```
app/design/frontend/Theme/Package/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml

<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
?>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know in which file should I add the above code? Thanks in advance

Comment: where you want to display Category name

Comment: I want to display the Category name above the Product Name in the catalog-view-page

Comment: app/design/frontend/Theme/Package/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Comment: I don't know exact path enable template path hints then you will get exact path

Comment: When I try adding the above code t the file specified, I get an "This page isn’t working" Error, Can you please help?

Comment: Where you add  ??????

Comment: app/design/frontend/Theme/Package/Magento_Catalog/templates/‌​product/view/form.ph‌​tml

Comment: you added under your theme only

Comment: in app/etc/env.php set 'MAGE_MODE' => 'develoer', then you will get exact error in frontend

Comment: It's under developer only, I get the following error when I try to echo "This page isn’t working 139.59.31.16 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: I even tried adding it in a new phtml file and adding the in the xml file, but unless I comment the echo statements, it throws the above error, can you please help me?

Comment: Check tag's are closed properley this is Working code only

Comment: Upload Your Full file here (form.phtml)

Comment: `<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
 */
?>
<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
   echo $category->getId();
   echo $category->getName();
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output'); ?>`

Comment: `<div class="product-add-form">
    <form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />`

Comment: `<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_top'); ?>
        <?php if (!$block->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_info_form_content'); ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container1'):?>
                <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: ` <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions() && $block->getOptionsContainer() == 'container2'):?>
            <?php echo $block->getChildChildHtml('options_container') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_bottom'); ?>
    </form>
</div>`

Comment: `<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-box'
    ], function($){
        var priceBoxes = $('[data-role=priceBox]');

        priceBoxes = priceBoxes.filter(function(index, elem){
            return !$(elem).find('.price-from').length;
        });

        priceBoxes.priceBox({'priceConfig': <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>});
    });
</script>`

Comment: I've uploaded the full code of the file above, When I comment the echo statements for the category page, The page displays. But if i uncomment it, It throws the above error

Comment: Update you Question there you will add full code

Comment: Works now, Thanks a Ton, Thank you so much

Comment: What is the problem What mistake you ????

Comment: I was trying in form.phtml, which did not work, then I created a seperate phtml file and included them in the xml file which worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to get category Data:

**=> Using Object Manager:**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$currentCategory = $registry->registry('current_category');
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
echo $currentCategory->getUrl() ;
```

**=> Using Block :**

**1) Create Block:**

> app/code/Allin/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

```
<?php
namespace Allin\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
?>
```

**2) Get current category in any template (.phtml) file**

```
// print current category data
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
echo $currentCategory->getUrl() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show current category name using following methods.

**Method 1. Using dependency injection**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/CurrentCategory.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class CurrentCategory extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/current_category.phtml

```
echo $block->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CurrentCategory" name="current.category" template="Vendor_Module::current_category.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="current.category" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Method 2. Using objectManager**

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/current_category.phtml

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$current_category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');

echo $current_category->getName();
```

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="current.category" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/current_category.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="current.category" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title"/>
    </body>
</page>
```