# show category name in product detail page

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get the name of a category in the addtocart.phtml. I know products could be assigned to more then one category so I am fine with having a loop if need be. Anyway here is my code which i thought would display the name of the category that the product is in/being viewed in.
does anyone know how I should alter this?

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    $category_name = $category->getName();
```

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202423/how-to-display-category-name-in-product-page

Comment: using product id get all category name which assign this product ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display category name in product page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202423/how-to-display-category-name-in-product-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product'); /* You will get current product from here */
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /* You will get array of categories id */
foreach($categories as $category){
   $catData = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
   echo $catData->getName();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Product Id Get All Category Name Which Assign This Product**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($product_id);
    $categoryIds = $productFactory->getCategoryIds();
    foreach($categoryIds as $category)
    {
        $id = $category->getId();
        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($id);
        $categoryName =  $categoryFactory->getName();
    }
```